# create .bat file to clear apache logs

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create a batch file to clear my Apache error log files, because they keep getting large very quickly.  I tried using the following script:

```
@echo off
type NUL > C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs\access.log
type NUL > C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs\error.log
```

Unfortunately, this script doesn't work.  I am using Windows 7.  Any suggestions?

Comment: "Don't work" is never enough of a description of the problem.  Are you getting any error messages?  You might be running into access rights problems, but we can't tell you without more info.

Comment: I agree with Jeremy.  This question would be better if it also listed the specific error messages encountered.  That way, future searches for those error messages could lead here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Won't work - Apache keeps the log files open at all times. You'd have to stop Apache, THEN truncate, and restart Apache. Another option would be to use a [log rotater](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#rotation) to do this for you automatically.

Comment: In their docs: [Apache log rotation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#rotation).

Comment: i try stop the apache services and then run my .bat files, it won't work either.. wonder why? log rotater is an application?

Comment: does whatever account you're running the .bat under have writes to modify the log directory/files?

Comment: don't forget quotes around the whole path, otherwise you're probably doing your redirect on a file named `C:\Program`.

Comment: yeah it's the quotes...work like a charm now. Thanks @MarcB very appreciated :)

Comment: Since the quotes are a fundamental part of making the script given in the question work, I think it would be worth adding this point to the text of the answer.